# When using gcov, is there a way to avoid instrumenting the header files included in the cpp file?

Tags: c++, unit-testing, code-coverage, gcov

I instrument my productive code with the flags `-fprofile-arcs` and `-ftest-coverage`, then I test this code with unit tests. For the unit tests to compile and run, I am forced to make some fakes and mocks.

I can control during compilation which cpp files are instrumented and which ones are not. But, when compiling my productive code with flags for instrumentation, the code for the fakes and mocks will also be included through the header files.

***Is there a way to avoid instrumenting the header files included in the cpp files?***, for example using some attribute, pre processor directive or compilation flag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there should be no way. What `#include` does is actually putting content inside cpp file before its compilation.

Comment: you are probable right, there is probably no way to accomplish what I want, but I had the hope (still have) that there is a preprocessor directive which tells the compiler to let some piece of code in a file uninstrumented.

Comment: @ArturoGonzalez Did you find any solution to this?

Comment: @user2148571 no, I could not find anything. I think it would be good to ask the gcov developers to implement such fuctionality. I think, it would not be very complex and could benefit many people.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the function attribute no_instrument_function to suppress profiling of individual functions when compiling with instrumenting options.

see:
https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-9.3.0/gcc/Instrumentation-Options.html
https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-9.3.0/gcc/Common-Function-Attributes.html#Common-Function-Attributes